# How to set coding sample content in timymce form database?

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

Firstly I store the coding sample content by using `tinymce` to the database, but when I try to set that data from database to `tinymce` is not able to execute.

[image]

Here are the ways I tried:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    echo htmlentities($fetch_results[0]['post_content']);
} else {
}
?>

    tinymce.get("posttextarea").setContent("<?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    echo htmlentities($fetch_results[0]['post_content']);
} else {
}
?>");

    tinymce.get("posttextarea").getBody().innerHTML = "<?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    echo $fetch_results[0]['post_content'];
} else {
}
?>";

    <textarea class="form-control" id="posttextarea" name="posttextarea" rows="15" required><?php
if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
    echo $fetch_results[0]['post_content'];
} else {
}
?></textarea>
```

I only want the same code sample as we first enter in the `tinymce`, when we retrieved from the database.

Comment: "is not able to execute" - are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: i'm using inside the setcontent("<?php if(isset($_GET['post'])){ echo htmlentities($fetch_results[0]['post_content']); }else{}  ?>");

Comment: and the errror was - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: So you're trying to use PHP inside JavaScript? This will only work if the js file is being parsed by PHP or if you're using it inside a script tag inside a php file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it in PHP file. can you elaborate on it?

Comment: var content = "&lt;pre class=&quot;language-php&quot;&gt;&lt;code&gt;&amp;lt;?php; the error output is like this